# Main activity not assigning values to variables

Tags: java, android, android-intent

In my homework problem I am supposed to calculate a monthly loan payment based on the loan amount interest rate and length of the loan given by the user. This is to be done using intent.

When I run the application, the values of the variable never change from 0 and then it goes to the second page of the app where the results are supposed to be displayed but it says NaN where the result is supposed to be displayed.

I am very new to Android development and I have no clue where the problem is occurring so I posted all of the main Java code I have.

class named **Loan.java**

```
package com.example.collegeloanpayoffcalculator;

public class Loan
{

    public static double loanAmount = 0.0;
    public static double interestRate = 0.0;
    public static int loanDuration = 0;
    //public static double monthlyPayment = 0.0;
    public double amount;
    public double interest;
    public double duration;
    //public double payment;

    public Loan() {}

    public Loan(double amount, double interest, double duration)
    {
        this.amount = amount;
        this.interest = interest;
        this.duration = duration;
    }
}
```

class named **MainActivity.java**

```
   public void calculatePayment(View view)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, paymentViewActivity.class);
        EditText loanAmount = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loanAmount);
        Editable amount = loanAmount.getText();
        intent.putExtra("Loan.loanAmount", Double.valueOf(amount.toString()));

        EditText interestRate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.interestRateEditText);
        Editable interest = interestRate.getText();
        intent.putExtra(String.valueOf(Loan.interestRate), interest);

        RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.duration);
        int selected_id = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        RadioButton radio_b = (RadioButton) findViewById(selected_id);

        intent.putExtra(String.valueOf(Loan.loanDuration), radio_b.getText().toString());
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

class named **paymentViewActivity.java**

```
public class paymentViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_loan_payment);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        double amount = intent.getDoubleExtra("loanAmount", loanAmount);
        double interest = intent.getDoubleExtra("interestRate", interestRate);

        int duration = intent.getIntExtra("loanDuration", loanDuration);

        double payment = amount * interest / (1 - 1 / Math.pow(1 + interest, duration * 12));

        TextView Payment = findViewById(R.id.loanPayment);
        Payment.setText(Double.toString(payment));
    }
```

Comment: try using this library: https://github.com/kostasdrakonakis/android_navigator

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have different key when adding extended data to the intent. You're using the following in `"Loan.loanAmount"` key in `calculatePayment` method:

```
intent.putExtra("Loan.loanAmount", Double.valueOf(amount.toString()));
```

But you expect `"loanAmount"` in `paymentViewActivity` class:

```
public class paymentViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       ...
       double amount = intent.getDoubleExtra("loanAmount", loanAmount);
    }
```

please take a note that `Intent.putExtra(String, Value)` is using a key-value format for the parameter. A string is a key identifier for a specific value.

So, use the same key for your putExtra. The safer way is using a constant String as a key in your related Activity. For example, use `LOAN_AMOUNT_KEY` constant string for your loan amount value:

```
public class paymentViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  public static final String LOAN_AMOUNT_KEY = "loanAmountKey";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       ...

       // use the key to find the value
       // you won't use the incorrect key because
       // the key is tightly coupled to the activity
       double amount = intent.getDoubleExtra(LOAN_AMOUNT_KEY, loanAmount);
    }
}
```

then, in your `calculatePayment` method, use the key when saving the value:

```
public void calculatePayment(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, paymentViewActivity.class);
    ...
    double amount = Double.valueOf(amount.toString());
    intent.putExtra(paymentViewActivity.LOAN_AMOUNT_KEY, amount);

    ...
 }
```

---

**Note:**

1. Use a correct java naming convention class name for your activity. For example, use `PaymentViewActivity` instead `paymentViewActivity`
2. Avoid using `public static` for your model member class. You're better use getter/setter.

Answer (score -1):

```
intent.putExtra(String.valueOf(Loan.interestRate), interest); --> wrong

intent.putExtra(String.valueOf(Loan.loanDuration), radio_b.getText().toString());
```

You need to add String name only then you will get it from extras.

```
intent.putExtra("interest", interest);
intent.putExtra("loanduration", radio_b.getText().toString());
```